# How to properly add app's scripts and styles in Vue-Laravel App?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I just started coding a Laravel and Vue.js based web application
I ran into a problem which is how to properly include styles and scripts in the application.
Currently my spa blade looks like this and I don't think it will be very clean when I go further:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="loading dark-layout" lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}" data-layout="dark-layout"
      data-textdirection="ltr">
<!-- BEGIN: Head-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0,minimal-ui">
    <meta name="description"
          content="Vuexy admin is super flexible, powerful, clean &amp; modern responsive bootstrap 4 admin template with unlimited possibilities.">
    <meta name="keywords"
          content="admin template, Vuexy admin template, dashboard template, flat admin template, responsive admin template, web app">
    <meta name="author" content="PIXINVENT">
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/images/ico/apple-icon-120.png') }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('/favicon.ico') }}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;1,400;1,500;1,600"
          rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <!-- BEGIN: Vendor CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/vendors/css/vendors.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/vendors/css/charts/apexcharts.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/vendors/css/extensions/toastr.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/vendors/css/animate/animate.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/vendors/css/extensions/sweetalert2.min.css') }}">
    <!-- END: Vendor CSS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Theme CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/bootstrap-extended.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/colors.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/components.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/themes/dark-layout.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/themes/bordered-layout.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/themes/semi-dark-layout.min.css') }}">

    <!-- BEGIN: Page CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/core/menu/menu-types/horizontal-menu.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/plugins/forms/form-validation.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/pages/page-auth.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/pages/dashboard-ecommerce.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/plugins/charts/chart-apex.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/plugins/extensions/ext-component-toastr.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/plugins/extensions/ext-component-sweet-alerts.min.css') }}">
    <!-- END: Page CSS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Custom CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/style.css') }}">
    <!-- END: Custom CSS-->

</head>
<!-- END: Head-->

<!-- BEGIN: Body-->
<body class="">

<div id="app"></div>

<!-- BEGIN: Vendor JS-->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/admin/vendors/js/vendors.min.js') }}"></script>
<!-- END: Vendor JS-->

<!-- BEGIN: Page Vendor JS-->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/admin/vendors/js/ui/jquery.sticky.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/admin/vendors/js/charts/apexcharts.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/admin/vendors/js/extensions/toastr.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/admin/vendors/js/extensions/sweetalert2.all.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/admin/vendors/js/extensions/polyfill.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/admin/vendors/js/forms/validation/jquery.validate.min.js') }}"></script>
<!-- END: Page Vendor JS-->

<!-- BEGIN: Theme JS-->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/admin/js/core/app-menu.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/admin/js/core/app.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/admin/js/scripts/customizer.min.js') }}"></script>
<!-- END: Theme JS-->

<!-- BEGIN: App JS-->
<script src="{{ mix('assets/admin/js/app.js') }}"></script>
<!-- END: App JS-->

<script>
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        if (feather) {
            feather.replace({width: 14, height: 14});
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
<!-- END: Body-->
</html>
```

the problem is that each page of the template has different styles and scripts, and not all of them are always needed everywhere.

I appriciate any advice, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add all your code in a snippet here instead of linking images. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's not clear. You must compile your assets into one, maybe two files using [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#sass).

For js, e.g. For css - read the docs

resources/js/bootstrap.js

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
//more requires
```

You can separate your assets for more files (public and admin, maybe), making more files and adding it to webpack.mix.js

Than, after run npm run dev - you will see compiled assets in public directory and can include this files into blade.

Comment: Thanks for responding, you recommend to require each style or script for each page  directly inside their component(using import/require)?

Comment: Not, you require all of your assets into bootstrap.js, app.scss and compile it in app.js / app.css with Laravel Mix and in blade require ONLY app.js and app.css

Comment: All of the styles and scripts? it's a good way but my purpose was to include each style and script in it's own page is this possible?

Comment: It's possible by your way - like in question. But it's wrong way.\

Comment: Understood! so I just include all of the styles & scripts into the bootstrap.js(without being concerned about the final app.js&app.css sizes) and it shall be fine?

Comment: Maybe, require it and try npm run dev - than debug all errors - and all will be fine